# Как отправить get запрос на url c ЧПУ

Tags: php, post, get

Мне нужно отправить get запрос на URL `test.ru/stop/search/{название}`, так же на `test.ru/route/search/{название1}/{название2}/{название3}`

Каким образом это делается, если нету названия параметров?

Что пытаюсь сделать:

```
    $url = 'http://test.ru/stop/search/Москва'
    $headers = array (
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->access_token,
        );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $x = curl_exec($ch);
```

Выдаёт `HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.`

Comment: Как вы можете отправлять GET запрос на ссылку которой нет??! конечно будет выдавать error 400 или 404.

Comment: @Arsen вы имеете виду test.ru? Там другой адрес

Comment: нет конечно, как можно отправлять запрос на ссылку test.ru/route/search/{название1}/{название2}/{название3}
если незнаешь значения {название1}/{название2}/{название3}

Comment: @Arsen, представьте себе, можно

Comment: @Gedweb серёзно? ) интерестно и что вы получите в ответ ? error 400? если вы незнаете ссылку, как можете отправить данные туда? ) это тоже самое что я скажу, позвони мне по телефону и скажу вам только первые две цыфры )))) сможете позвонить?

Comment: @Arsen, mod_rewrite в руки

Comment: @Gedweb - насколько мне(!) понятно из вопроса, товаришь Zhi V хочет сделать GET запрос на чужой ресурс (другой сайт), при чём тут ваш mod_rewite ? или я неверно понял вопрос?  
Zhi V -вы на своём сайте отправляете GET запросы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я думаю стоит url через `urlencode` стоит прогнать

```
 $url = 'http://test.ru/stop/search/'+urlencode('Москва');
```

Comment: Бред `http%3A%2F%2Ftest.ru%2Fstop%2Fsearch%2F%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0`.

Comment: @Visman хах что вас смущает, сервер просто не понимает русские символы по этому и выбрасывает 400 (bad request) а так он поймёт и расшифрует нормально в GET.

Comment: Смущает меня преобразование двоеточия и слэшей.

Comment: @Visman да вы правы правы тут стоит только русские символы закодировать...

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать посмотреть в сторону модуля Apache mod_rewrite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136521/apache-mod-rewrite-path-name-as-query-parameters

Но конечно же лучше перенаправлять все входящие запросы на индексовый файл и уже в скриптах обрабатывать ЧПУ.